# Unable to add permissions to App on Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I have created an app on Azure Portal to access some information via Microsoft Graph API but I am not able to add any permissions to it. It was working earlier but not any more. I also tried to register a new app, the app gets register but yet again the permissions could not be added.

As soon as I press the button to add the selected permissions these two popup notifications come up ..
1. Your session will end in a few minutes. You will have to refresh your browser to start a new session.
2. The portal is having issues getting an authentication token. The experience rendered may be degraded.

Additional information from the call to get a token:
Extension: Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps

This is happening since last 3 days now. I also searched on Google and found that people had similar issues earlier as well. Though I have raised a ticket on the portal for this but haven't received any reply yet.

Any help here would be very much appreciated. Also is there any way to check any logs on the portal itself. I did try to check the network logs via browser developer tools but they aren't much help.

[image: Notifications]

Comment: It looks like a back-end issue which only azure support team can help you. [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7aa9512-5e20-458b-be04-b1ef78232c88/register-a-new-application-using-the-azure-portal-unable-to-obtain-api-permissions?forum=azureapimgmt) is a similar issue, please check if it may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there was an issue with my account address. I changed the address to one of US and it worked for me.

@Allen Wu Thanks for the suggestions. I had already asked them about it but no one replied.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the Azure Portal for your region.

As @Hury Shen suggested, you should contact Azure Support for further investigation.

See [how to open a support ticket on Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).